# How to know when the question mark key is pressed in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a key down event, how can I know when the <kbd>?</kbd> key is pressed (on all platforms)?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need compare the `PlatformKeyCode` property from the `KeyEventArgs`. Just know that this codes are OS specific, so you need to use the `BrowserInformation` class from `System.Windows.Browser` to detect the client OS.

Here you can get Windows Virtual-Key Codes [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645540)